# How can i use Yii.ActiveRecord to find unrelated records?

Tags: yii

I have two models with relation:

```
class Model1 extends CActiveRecord
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'relation' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Model2', 'id_model1'),
  )
}
```

I want view by CListView those records from Model 1, which **unrelated** with Model2.
Obvious, I can use something like

```
$criteria->condition = 'id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_model1 FROM model2_tbl)'
```

and then send this $criteria to ActiveDataProvider. 
But I look for something more smart, more "yii-way" for solution. Is it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Relational query options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) `'joinType' = 'RIGHT OUTER'` and `'condition'=>'left_table.join_field IS NULL'` might do the trick.